# How to copy new entry or new line of a growing log file in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, logging

I am learning shell script.

I need to capture every new entry or new line in to a log file and copy the line to another file.

Example: I want to copy every new entry in /var/log/maillog to //newlog.log

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tail -0f /var/log/maillog | tee -a ../newlog.log
```

The `0` in `-0f` is to not copy existing tail entries, and start tailing only new entries. `tee` is used to redirect stdout to another location. The `-a` option, as folks have pointed out, is used to append to the output file rather than overwrite it.

Comment: To append use tee -a too because he wants to add every new entry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. i tried it but it is copying all the lines from maillog to newlog, but i want only the new entry (upcoming entry) to be copied to newlog file or else the entry with specific keyword in it.

Comment: Do `tail -0f` in that case. (Edited). @devnull, thanks for the `-a` edit!

Comment: if you want to add a specific line then you have to use grep like say i want so search the line with puligilla and add that line to newlog.log you can use grep -i "puligilla" /var/log/mail.log | tee -a newlog.log

Comment: tail -0f /var/log/maillog | tee -a ../newlog.log worked for me... thanks for the quick replies and help.